# Clear selection in WebKit2 Web Extension without JavaScript

Tags: webkit2, webkit2-webextension

I want to clear the selection from a web extension.

There is a signal [`selection-changed`](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitWebEditor.html#WebKitWebEditor-selection-changed), but there does not seem to have a way to clear the selection.

I tried creating a [`WebKitDOMRange`](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitdomgtk/stable/WebKitDOMRange.html) but it seems there is no way to set this new range in the document.
And it does not seem to have a way to get the current range.

How can I clear the selection from a WebKit2 web extension without using a JavaScript string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebKit2 seems to have an unstable API that does not appear in the documentation.

I was able to get the current selection with the [`webkit_dom_dom_window_get_selection`](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/45e7d4ba905a6c24c55bdb306d642e5909de6513/Source/WebKit2/WebProcess/InjectedBundle/API/gtk/DOM/WebKitDOMDOMWindow.h#L61) and clearing it with [`webkit_dom_dom_selection_empty`](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/45e7d4ba905a6c24c55bdb306d642e5909de6513/Source/WebKit2/WebProcess/InjectedBundle/API/gtk/DOM/WebKitDOMDOMSelection.h#L190)